# How to go same screen with different data from React native flat List

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, onpress

I'm new in React Native and I've FlatList with some items I want to use code like when I click any item on the flat list a screen open and shows data of that item related.When I click on another item same screen open but with data related to that item.Means resuability.

Comment: there are multiple ways you can do it, using navigations params, using redux, etc. Can you be give more details how you are going to another screen? small code snippets will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values in renderItem.  renderItem is called for each and every item flatlist renders and simultaneously you will get the index also of each item.

```
   <FlatList
          style={styles.FlatListStyle}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <Button title = 'hello'
onPress = {() =>alert(item)}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <Button onPress={() => navigate('Details', {data: item})} />
    )}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

For navigation purpose, You've to use `react-navigation` package. Then `onPress` you can simply call `navigation.push` method to navigate to a different or same stack(screen).

e.g

`navigation.push("SameScreen",{newData:"value"})`